# jQuery Function interation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my coding pls check the following code

```
var sliderFunction = {
  init: function(sliderSettings) {
    sliderFunction.sliderSettings();
  },
  sliderSettings: function() {
    var sliderDiv = $('.slider');
    var ulDiv = $('.slider ul');
    var liDiv = $('.slider ul li');

    var sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width();
    var countLi = liDiv.length;
    var ulTotalWidth = sliderWidth * countLi;

    ulDiv.outerWidth(ulTotalWidth);
  },
  nextContent: function() {
  }
}

sliderFunction.init();
```

I want sliderSettings function's var access in nextContent function. How can I do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't, scope issues.

Answer (score 1):

define them in the global scope and they'll be accessible anywhwere

```
 var sliderDiv,ulDiv,liDiv,sliderWidth,countLi,ulTotalWidth,ulDiv;
var sliderFunction = {
  init: function(sliderSettings) {
  sliderFunction.sliderSettings();
},
sliderSettings: function() {
 sliderDiv = $('.slider');
 ulDiv = $('.slider ul');
 liDiv = $('.slider ul li');

 sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width();
 countLi = liDiv.length;
 ulTotalWidth = sliderWidth * countLi;

 ulDiv.outerWidth(ulTotalWidth);
},

nextContent:function(){
    console.log(sliderDiv,ulDiv,liDiv,sliderWidth,countLi,ulTotalWidth,ulDiv);
}
}
```